# Count documents in a firestore collection with BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'd like to setup a dashboard to count the number of documents that exist in a certain collection in my Cloud Firestore database. Is there a way to do this with BigQuery?

I'm guessing this should be straightforward, but I haven't found any documentation or examples of doing so. I found all kinds of examples to query events that I log, but nothing to count the number of documents in a specific collection.

Comment: Are your collections/subcollections in BigQuery?

Comment: Thanks, with your comment I realized I had to explicitly export collections to BigQuery. Works now!